# .NET Testing Naming Conventions

Tags: .net, unit-testing, testing, naming, conventions

What are the best conventions of naming testing-assemblies in .NET (or any other language or platform)?

What I'm mainly split between are these options (please provide others!):

- **Company.Website** - *the project*
- **Company.Website.Tests**

*or*

- **Company.Website**
- **Company.WebsiteTests**

The problem with the first solution is that it looks like .Tests are a sub-namespace to the site, while they really are more parallel in my mind. What happens when a new sub-namespace comes into play, like **Company.Website.Controls**, where should I put the tests for that namespace, for instance?

Maybe it should even be: **Tests.Company.Website** and **Tests.Company.Website.Controls**, and so on.

Comment: Why is this closed? All 'opinion-based' answer is still an answer where users can view a list of options and choose what they feel is best for them.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I will go with

```
* Company.Website - the project
* Company.Website.Tests
```

The short reason and answer is simple, testing and project are linked in code, therefore it should share namespace.

If you want splitting of code and testing in a solution you have that option anyway. e.g. you can set up a solution with

-Code Folder

- Company.Website

-Tests Folder

- Company.Website.Tests

Comment: Also you don't need to add a using for the Company.Website namespace this way.

Answer (score 13):

I personally would go with

Company.Tests.Website

That way you have a common tests namespace and projects inside it, following the same structure as the actual project.

Answer (score 7):

I actually have an alternate parallel root.

Tests.Company.Website

It works nicely for disambiguating things when you have new sub namespaces.

Comment: Why the downvote? Could the critic elaborate on that? It's as good as any other proposed solution - and have a good point.

Comment: This does cause problems with referenced namespaces though. It is a bit of a headache sometimes, as to why I am searching SO for the suggest way of doing it.. (i did not down vote)

Answer (score 5):

I'm a big fan of structuring the test namespace like this:

**Company.Tests.Website.xxx**

**Company.Tests.Website.Controls**

Like you, I think of the tests as a parallel namespace structure to the main code and this provides you with that. It also has the advantage that, since the namespace still starts with your company name you shouldn't have any naming collisions with 3rd party libraries

Answer (score 2):

We follow an embedded approach:

```
Company.Namespace.Test
Company.Namespace.Data.Test
```

This way the tests are close to the code that is being tested, without having to toggle back and forth between projects or hunt down references to ensure there is a test covering a particular method. We also don't have to maintain two separate, but identical, hierarchies.

We can also test distinct parts of the code as we enhance and develop.

Seems a little weird at first, but over the long term it has worked really well for us.

Answer (score 1):

I too prefer "Tests" prefixing the actual name of the assembly so that its easy to see all of my unit test assemblies listed alphabetically together when I mass-select them to pull into NUNit or whatever test harness you are using.

So if Website were the name of my solution (and assemblies), I suggest -

**Tests.Website.dll** to go along with the actual code assembly **Website.Dll**

Answer (score 0):

I usually name test projects *Project-Tests* for brevity in Solution Explorer, and I use *Company.Namespace.Tests* for namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to go with:

Company.Website.Tests

I don't care about any sub-namespaces like Company.Website.Controls, all of the tests go into the same namespace: Company.Website.Tests.  You don't want your test namespaces to HAVE to be in parrallel with the rest of your code because it just makes refactoring namespaces take twice as long.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer Company.Website.Spec and usually have one test project per solution

Answer (score 0):

With MVC starting to become a reality in the .net web development world, I would start thinking along those lines. Remember that M, V and C are distinct components, so:

- Company.Namespace.Website
- Company.Namespace.Website.Core
- Company.Namspance.Website.Core.Tests
- Company.Namespace.Website.Model
- Company.Namespace.Website.Model.Tests

Website is your lightweight view. 
Core contains controllers, helpers, the view interfaces, etc. Core.Tests are your tests for said Core.
Model is for your data model. The cool thing here is that your model tests can automate your database specific tests.

This may be overkill for some people, but I find that it allows me to separate concerns fairly easily.

Comment: "starting to become a reality" omfg